# conditional proposition vs biconditional proposition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I have been working on college and am currently in a math class. The following question came up and I chose "->" as the answer. This was marked wrong  and I challenged the answer but was told this is in our readings. I have been doing some "googling" (as well as read study material) and I cannot seem to see how I was wrong. Perhaps someone can shine some light on why my thought process is incorrect? From my understanding **"<->" is a biconditional proposition** AND **"->" is a conditional proposition**. If the tags are incorrect please let me know. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Learner answer is what I chose.

Comment: This is odd. It's a matter of taste. I would've chosen the one way option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: $\to$

A conditional proposition is an "If *antecedent*, then *consequent*" form of statement.   The connective used for this is indeed: $\to$.

---

Statements of equivalence are biconditionals, and the connective used for these is: $\leftrightarrow$

Comment: Thank you very much. Time to go get a test-question resolved :).